# Hibernate Criterion - join between more tables

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I've got a problem with this situation (i'll try to make it easier) - there are users in my DB with list of roles and list of statuses.

```
public class User implements Serializable {   
   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)   
   @JoinTable(name = "role_to_user",
               joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
     private Set<Role> roles = new LinkedHashSet<Role>();      
   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)   
   @JoinTable(name = "status_to_user",
              joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "status_id")})   
     private Set<Status> statuses = new LinkedHashSet<Status>(); 
}
```

I am trying to create a hibernate criteria, which was abble to return users (after join with role table and status table) with specified roles and statuses. Something like :

> return users with role = 1 or role = 2 and status = 1

I googled something and now I can create a query which returns me users only with specified roles, but not statuses.

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class)
                     .createCriteria("roles")
                     .add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("roletype", 1), Restrictions.eq("roletype", 2)));
```

Table user and role are connected through role_to_user table with two columns (user_id, role_id), similarly in the same way table user and status through status_to_role table

Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class, "user")
                     .createAlias("user.roles", "role", Criteria.INNER_JOIN)
                     .createAlias("user.statuses", "status", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
cr.add(Restrictions.or(
           Restrictions.eq("role.roletype", 1),
           Restrictions.and(
               Restrictions.eq("role.roletype", 2),
               Restrictions.eq("status.statusType", 1))));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Working flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks save my time!:)